# inserting data iff there are no duplicated datas in mysql db

Tags: mysql, mybatis

```
<insert id="insertStockOrderAbusingList" parameterType="java.util.List">
    INSERT IGNORE INTO iruda_trade.stock_order_abusing (
        market_day,
        uid,
        stock_account_id,
        order_number,
        symbol,
        conclusion_quantity,
        order_type,
        created_at
    ) VALUES
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=",">
    (
            #{item.transactionDate},
            #{item.uid},
            #{item.stockAccountId},
            #{item.transactionNumber},
            #{item.symbol},
            #{item.filledVolume},
            #{item.transactionType},
            #{item.clientTimeStamp}
     )
     </foreach>
</insert>
```

I'm trying to insert the datas in mySQL DB. if transactionDate, transactionNumber, and uid from parameters are same with market_day, order_number, uid from stock_order_abusing table columns at the same time, then there will be no insertion or insertion should be ignored. There are no pk(primary key) to compare. All the methods in google are telling me that I should have primary key to prevent duplicated insertion. Are there any ways to deal with this problem?

Comment: 'If you use the IGNORE modifier, ignorable errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html Can you create an appropriate key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT IGNORE syntax if you want to take no action when there's a duplicate record.

[here is full syntax guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

Comment: This is not an appropriate solution , op has stated there is no primary key, and I suppose no unique key, to identify a duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database structure, you can create unique indexes on the
"uid" field. In this way, the database prevents double entry of data

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name  
ON table_name (index_column1, index_column2,...);
```